# SQL: Relation between different rows of two tables

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I'm creating er-diagram for "Airport" database. And I got stick with tables "Flight" and "Airport" .
In table "Flight" I have 2 columns: "Departure_place" and "Arrival_ place". Both of it should be connected to values in table "Airport".
So, How can I make that in the proper way on er-diagram and on sql?

[image]

Comment: what's arrival place?

Comment: *I have 2 rows: "Departure_place" and "Arrival_ place"* do you mean, row columns?

Comment: Your question is fairly thin.  Are you looking for a full database schema here, or do you just need a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: I need just pointer ONLY for reference for two fields to "Airport" table

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for **foreign keys**. Here is a tutorial for that:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

In your case first create the tables:

```
create table flight(
  idFlight int primary key,
  idDeparturePlace int,
  idArrivalPlace int);

create table airport(
  idAirport int primary key);
```

Now you have to add tow foreign keys. One for `idDepaturePlace` and one for `idArrivalPlace`.

Follow this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE <child table> ADD FOREIGN KEY (<col in child table>) REFERENCES <master table>(<col in master table>);
```

In your case you have to add this both keys to your flight table:

```
ALTER TABLE flight ADD FOREIGN KEY (idDepaturePlace) REFERENCES airport(idAirport);

ALTER TABLE flight ADD FOREIGN KEY (idArrivalPlace) REFERENCES airport(idAirport);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have another question.

Comment: What for another question?

Comment: I added image for illustration question .